# custom sorting of arrays in php using usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

i want to sort the dir list that i get in an array in a custom order.

i did try using the usort but am not getting the desired result.

also i want u to explain the $a and $b used here in usort.

```
$dir    = '/tmp';

$dir_list=scan_dir($dir);

//now this $dir_list array for the sake of this example contains the following elements

$dir_list=array('dir1','dir2','newdir2','string1');

$order=array('newdir2','dir1','string1','dir2');

//all the values in both the arrays are strings.
```

i found the following solution here but please explain what is the use of $a, $b and the keyword 'use'

```
usort($dir_list, function ($a, $b) use ($order) 
{

    $pos_a = array_search($a['id'], $order);

    $pos_b = array_search($b['id'], $order);

    return $pos_a - $pos_b;

});

var_dump($dir_list);
```

Comment: Have your read `usort` description? (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Answer (score 0):

usort is the function the sort an array according to user define function.
If we talk about basic concept of sort an array, array sorting always match two members of array to see which one is greater or less than or equals, therefore, $a, $b are the two members of $dir_list array(could be at any index) going to be compare at any iteration of sorting.

new keyword is used to inherits variables from parent scope. Like in above example you need to use $order but $order is define outside the anonymous function, so use keywords is there to import the $order variable inside the scope of the anonymous function.